# d3.selectAll to change styles by class in v4

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm transitioning from d3 v3 to d3 v4. I've looked through the documentation on what's changed, and I know that styles and selectors work a little differently now. I'm having an issue finding the right way to get what I need done.

In v3 I could do this:

```
d3.selectAll(".myRectangle").style({'fill':'rgb(255,100,100)', 'stroke':'#000', 'stroke-width':'0.3'});
```

at the bottom of my code and everything that was classed as "myRectangle" that had been drawn would get the specified style applied to it.

Also, it would act as a placeholder in case anything dynamically got the myRectangle class added to them (say with a mouseover).

Now, the same code not only doesn't apply the styles, it returns an error if no element with the specified class exists.

I haven't been able to find an example of how to properly achieve this, which, might mean that I've been doing it poorly all along. Can anyone here point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In d3.js v4, `attr` and `style` only accept one attribute/value pair as parameters:

```
d3.selectAll('.myRectangle').style('fill', 'rgb(255,100,100)')
```

In order to pass an object with multiple values, you have to use `attrs` and `styles` instead of `attr` and `style` and also include https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js file in your web page.

Alternatively, you may chain several `attr`, one for each attribute. Idem for `style`.

Reference: [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Eggy. I'm using the megalib for v4, but added selection-multi to the page too just to be sure. I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: d3.selectAll(...).styles is not a function". I'm able to work around some of my issues with what you've given me, so thanks for that at least.

Comment: The only thing I can figure out is the order in which you embed d3 modules: `d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js` must appear *after* `d3.v4.min.js`.

Comment: I downloaded d3-selection-multi locally and it works just fine. Must've been a network issue with my company's firewall. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The other post is correct that you can only set one attribute or style to one thing at a time. But "style" is an attribute, which accepts a single string!

```
d3.selectAll('.myRectangle').attr("style", "fill:rgb(255,100,100);stroke:#000;stroke-width:0.3;")
```

Comment: Despite the fact that this is not what OP is asking, your answer is indeed a good advice: OP can easily avoid the use of `d3-selection-multi` by passing a single string with all the styles. And welcome to StackOverflow.